# Changing to view from another view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

i am currently learning C# and WPF. I have started coding simple application, i have 
1 model class (Book), 
2 model views (BookListModelView, AddNewBookModelView) and 
2 views booth are UserControl (BookListView, AddNewBookView).

My question is how can i change to AddNewBookView when my current view is BookListView?

MainWindow.xaml :

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BookListModelView bookListMV = new BookListModelView();
        this.DataContext = bookListMV;
    }
}
```

BookListView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class BookListView : UserControl
{
    public BookListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NewBookBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new AddNewBookViewModel();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to achieve this is with DataTemplates. Basically you have a property in your main view model containing the view models of your child page:

```
public object PageViewModel {get; set;} // <--- needs property change notification
```

I've used `object` as the type here, whereas in practice you typically have some base class for your pages.

Over in your view you create a ContentControl and bind it to this property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PageViewModel}" />
```

Finally, you need to specify some kind of mapping specifying which view to display for each view model type. That's where data templates come in:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel1}">
    <local:ChildViewControl1 />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel2}">
    <local:ChildViewControl2 />
</DataTemplate>
```

Another way to achieve this is via Data Triggers. These get put in the parent's style and check for each possible value, setting the content explicitly:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageViewModelProperty}" Value="SomeChildViewModel1Value">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyPageTemplate1}" />
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PageViewModelProperty}" Value="SomeChildViewModel2Value">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyPageTemplate2}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

... and so on. This is a better fit in cases where you may not have a separate class type for each of your page types e.g. in the case of page containing content that is generated dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for you help and answer! I have one more question, would you as professional C# developer choose this way when developing application with only one window? If not what would be the right/correct way? 

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Absolutely. Data templates are a fundamental, key component of WPF development, I use them in virtually every application I write. My current job, for example, includes writing kiosk software for airlines, where users have to navigate through the pages of a check-in application; data templates is how I usually implement that paging functionality.

Comment: And like I said, data triggers are handy for cases where data templates aren't appropriate, again I use them all the time. When the view can't consume data being provided by the view model people will often immediately fall back to writing a converter to do what could have been done with a data trigger. Golden rule is if view model data needs to drive something in the view, and it's a one-way conversion, use a data trigger. Converters should normally only be used if it's two-way. (Although people will often break this if it makes the XAML more readable e.g. BooleanToVisibility converters).